# Use multiple Textures in export loader `obj` file in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I tried to use different textures in export loader `obj` file.
I am able to make my object visible on the scene but I couldn't set either its size nor its shape.
Any idea on what is wrong/is missing in my code ?

```
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
loader.load(
  'models/Sofa/sofa.obj',
  function (object) {
      var geometry = object.children[ 0 ].geometry;
      var materials = [];
      materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/Sofa/Texturses/1.jpg')}));
      materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/Sofa/Texturses/paradis_beige.jpg')}));
      materials.push(new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map : THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/Sofa/Texturses/2.jpg')}));
      mesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geometry, materials);

      object.traverse(function (child) {
          if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
              child.material = material;
          }
      });
      scene1.add(mesh);
  },
  function ( xhr ) {
    returnValue = ( xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded';
    console.log(returnValue);
  },
  function ( error ) {
    console.log( 'An error happened' );
  }
);
```

Comment: Difficulties with "*I can able to visible my object but not*"... Do you mean 1) "*I am able to `visualize` my object but not...*" or do you mean 2) "*I  am able to `set visible to` my object but not...*" ?

Comment: Formatted code and fixed grammar